# C++ SoLoud library Visual Studio issue loading

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2019

I have this code

```
#include "SoundClass.h"
#include <soloud.h>
#include <soloud_wav.h>
#include <soloud_c.h>

SoLoud::Soloud gSoloud; 
SoLoud::Wav wave1;
SoLoud::Wav wave2;



 SoundClass::SoundClass()
{   
  // init sound

   gSoloud.init();
   wave1.load("pathtosound etc");
   wave2.load("pathtosound etc");
 }

 SoundClass::~SoundClass()
{
}



 void SoundClass::playSFX(const int which)
{
  switch (which) {
    case 1:
        gSoloud.play(wave1);
    break;
    case 2:
        gSoloud.play(wave2);
    break;
}
}
```

The code brings up no warnings or errors, in Visual Studio 2019.  So it appears all the header files are linked properly through the Include directories.

However I receive this error message when I try to build.

[image]

Comment: The error is message is trying to tell you that you need to list the "soloud" libraries as a dependency to your project.

Comment: I have "c:\dev\soloud\include" as an include folder on my project.  Which stopped the red underlined errors.  @drescherjm as for linking a library, there is no .lib file to link for SoLoud, by the looks of it??

Comment: I see in the 47 MB download that there are 2 dlls but not any .lib files to link. There is also source code but it requires a program called genie to generate project files using the file in the build folder: [https://github.com/bkaradzic/genie](https://github.com/bkaradzic/genie)

Comment: I have the same problem with  no .lib file to match the .dll files.  Any solution? Can someone add the .lib to the download zip file?

Comment: Solve sort of: Windows 10, Visual Studio 2019: I downloaded https://raw.githubusercontent.com/bkaradzic/bx/master/tools/bin/windows/genie.exe and put it in my PATH. Then simply got the source zip from https://github.com/bkaradzic/GENie.git. Then in the build directory ran genie vs2019 and it generate the project. Then in the project build both static and dynamic, both debug and release.  I end up with a directory with both .lib and .dll files. win64.

Comment: More: The default is only Win32. You also need to create the x64 builds in VS 2019 to create the correct version of the .lib files.  I use soloud_static.lib in my project and it works great.